# Instantiating ModelExpression directly

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Let's say I have the following `input` tag which utilizes the built-in tag helper:

```
@model ProductViewModel

<label asp-for="Product.Id"></label>
```

In my case, this expands into the following:

```
<label for="Product_Id">Id</label>
```

I see that `asp-for` is expecting a `ModelExpression`:

[image]

In tag helper implementations, I often see a property like the following:

```
public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
```

It appears that this is automatically populated when the tag helper is used.

Is there a way to instantiate a `ModelExpression` directly in C#?

I.e. something like this:

```
var exp = new ModelExpression("Product.Id",...)
```

I'd like to be able to generate "Product_Id" and "Id" from `Product.Id` as the `input` tag helper did.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can specify that your property is to be set to the name of some property on the View's Model object by declaring your property with the ModelExpression type. This will enable any developer using your property to get IntelliSense support for entering a property name from the Model object. More importantly, your code will be passed the value of that property through the ModelExpression's Model property.

Sample code as below:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("employee-details")]
public class EmployeeDetailTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("for-name")]
    public ModelExpression EmployeeName { get; set; }
    [HtmlAttributeName("for-designation")]
    public ModelExpression Designation { get; set; }
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "EmployeeDetails";
        output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("<span>Name: {0}</span> <br/>", this.EmployeeName.Model);
        sb.AppendFormat("<span>Designation: {0}</span>", this.Designation.Model);

        output.PreContent.SetHtmlContent(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Code in the View page:

```
@model WebApplication7.Models.EmployeeViewModel
<div class="row">
    <employee-details for-name="Name" for-designation="Designation"></employee-details>
</div>
```

Code in the Model

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
}
```

From above code, you can see that we could custom the attribute name. More detail information about using the ModelExpression, check the following links:

[Creating Custom Tag Helpers With ASP.NET Core MVC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-custom-tag-helpers-with-asp-net-core-mvc/)

[Expression names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#expression-names)

> I'd like to be able to generate "Product_Id" and "Id" from Product.Id
> as the input tag helper did.

Besides, do you mean you want to change the `Product. Id` to `Product_Id`, in my opinion, I'm not suggesting you change it, because generally we can use "_" as a separator in the property name. So, if we are using `Product.Id`, it means the Product's Id property, and the `Product_Id` means there have a `Product_Id` property.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question:

> Is there a way to instantiate a ModelExpression directly in C#"

Yes you can, through [IModelExpressionProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.imodelexpressionprovider) and its [CreateModelExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.imodelexpressionprovider.createmodelexpression) method. You can get an instance of this interface through DI.

Now, if you're already in your view and working with tag helpers, [Zhi Lv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64203465/1245184) is all you need, as the functionality is built-in and much easier to use. You only need `IModelExpressionProvider` for when you're in your Razor Page, Controller, or perhaps some custom middleware. Personally, I find this functionality useful for my Ajax handlers that need to return one of my `ViewComponent`s that has a `ModelExpression` argument (so that I can easily call it from my Pages/Views too.)

To call `CreateModelExpression`, you'll need a strongly-typed instance of `ViewData`. In Razor Pages, this is as easy as casting the [ViewData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel.viewdata) property to the strongly-typed instance of your PageModel's type (presuming you don't have a page model hierarchy):

```
var viewData = (ViewDataDictionary<IndexModel>)ViewData;
```

If you're using MVC and you're in the controller, that won't exist yet. Best you can do is make your own instance.

```
var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<ErrorViewModel>(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
    new ModelStateDictionary());
```

Once you get your strongly-typed ViewData instance, you can obtain your desired `ModelExpression` like this, just like using a lambda expression in your views:

```
var myPropertyEx = _modelExpressionProvider.CreateModelExpression(viewData,
    m => m.MyProperty);
```

Comment: Do you happen to know whether there is any way to bind such a created ModelExpression to an `asp-for` tag helper attribute in a manner that works?

Comment: @Neutrino, afraid not. It seems the code generated for a Razor view always assumes what you put into the `asp-for` attribute needs to be converted to a ModelExpression, even if it, itself, already is one. [And they probably won't fix it.](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/926) The only workaround I could think of is creating a ViewComponent which accepts your ModelExpression, which is what they recommend you do in that link.

Comment: As best I can tell this doesn't work with a ViewComponent either. In that link the suggestion is to use what seems to be some out-of-date hack to extract a field name and value from a ModelExpression for use in a ViewComponent. Firstly that doesn't even seem to work anymore, and secondly it doesn't solve the issue in the general case where it isn't just the field name and value that's required, but a working reference to a property on an existing model from where the `asp-for` can correctly retrieve data and validation attributes. I've seen nothing so far that makes this work.